# PHP- Insert an Icon on a table column header

Tags: php, csv

I'm using this code for creating a table based on a CSV file and it works fine;

```
<?php
                $lines = file('graphdata/GapsVsOthersForDimsOthersJson.csv');       

                foreach ($lines as $lineNum => $line) {
    $cellType = ($lineNum == 0 ? "th" : "td");
    $tokens = str_getcsv($line);

    if ($lineNum == 0) echo "<thead>";
    if ($lineNum == 1) echo "<tbody>";

    echo "<tr id=\"tr" . $lineNum . "\">";
    echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 300px;\">" . trim($tokens[0]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
    echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[1]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
    echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[2]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
    echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[3]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
    echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[4]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
    echo "</tr>";
    if ($lineNum == 0) echo "</thead>";
}
if (count($lines) > 1) echo "</tbody>";
  ?>
```

I'm interested in inserting a button icon next the the **last column header** using:

```
<button id="popupWindowDimensions" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> 
</button>
```

Any idea?

Comment: add another `if ($lineNum == 0)` check after the code that displays the last column header (before the closing `tr` tag)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below format but this will create a empty last column

So Please can you clearly give how you need

```
 <?php
$lines = file('graphdata/GapsVsOthersForDimsOthersJson.csv');

foreach ($lines as $lineNum => $line) {
    $cellType = ($lineNum == 0 ? "th" : "td");
    $tokens = str_getcsv($line);

    if ($lineNum == 0) echo "<thead>";
    if ($lineNum == 1) echo "<tbody>";

    echo "<tr id=\"tr" . $lineNum . "\">";
    echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 300px;\">" . trim($tokens[0]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
    echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[1]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
    echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[2]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
    echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[3]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
    echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[4]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
    if ($lineNum == 0)
    {
        echo "<" . $cellType . ' style=\"width: 100px;\">';
        echo '<button id="popupWindowDimensions" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
        </button>';
        echo '</' . $cellType . '>';
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    if ($lineNum == 0) echo "</thead>";
}
if (count($lines) > 1) echo "</tbody>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. It indeed adds an empty column. I need the button icon to be  in the header cell of the last existing column just next to the header text or under it